# $X\setminus\{(1,0)\} \cong (0,1)$: showing two topological spaces are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$; that is, $X=\{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2=1 \}$ and has subspace topology.
>
> Show that $X\setminus\{(1,0)\} \cong (0,1)$.

How can I go about showing these two topological spaces are homeomorphic?

Comment: Use the stereographic projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints.**

- $\mathbb{S}^1\setminus\{(1,0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ using a stereographic projection of pole $(1,0)$, for example: $$(x,y)\mapsto\frac{y}{1-x}.$$
  Its inverse is given by:
  $$t\mapsto\left(\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1},\frac{2t}{t^2+1}\right).$$
  Both maps are continuous as rational fraction of the coordinates.
- $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$, for example:
  $$t\mapsto\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(t)+\frac{1}{2}.$$

Hence, one has $\mathbb{S}^1\setminus\{(1,0)\}\cong\mathbb{R}\cong(0,1)$.

Comment: would you mind proving that your map is a homeomorphism? And then showing how your second assertion ties it all together?

Comment: @ALannister See my edit and tell me if it is clearer.